# I have a variable in javascript that is not being set to the proper value

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var pizza = 0;
    var tops = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var tax = 0;
    var cheesecost = 0;

    function getcheese(yesno) {
        switch (yesno) {
            case 1:
                if (type == 1) {
                    cheesecost = 1;
                }
                if (type == 2) {
                    cheesecost = 1;
                }
                if (type == 3) {
                    cheesecost = 1.25;
                }
                if (type == 4) {
                    cheesecost = 1.4;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                cheesecost = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    function calc() {
        count = document.getElementById("toppingbox").value;
        subtotal = pizza + (tops * count) + cheesecost;
        tax = parseFloat(subtotal) * .06;
        total = parseFloat(tax) + parseFloat(subtotal);
        alert(cheesecost);
        document.getElementById("taxbox").value = tax.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("subtotalbox").value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("totalbox").value = total.toFixed(2);
    }

    function gettype(type) {
        if (type == 1) {
            pizza = 4;
            tops = .5;
        }
        if (type == 2) {
            pizza = 7.25;
            tops = .6;
        }
        if (type == 3) {
            pizza = 9.25;
            tops = .75;
        }
        if (type == 4) {
            pizza = 12.9;
            tops = .9;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 64px; background-color: #e6e6e6">
    <center>
        <h1>Online Pizza Order Form</h1>
    </center>
    <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center;width: 35%; height: 6px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px">
    <form>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div style="text-align: center; padding-left: 24px; padding-top: 16px; padding-right: 24px; padding-bottom: 16px; border-width: 2px; border-style: ridge; background-color:#d8d8d8; width:28%; margin-bottom: 4px;">
                <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; margin-top:-12px; height: 2px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-width: 2px"> <b>Select the pizza type</b>
                <br>
                <div style="padding-left: 64px; text-align: left; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>1. 6' - $4.00</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="1" onclick="gettype(this.value)">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2. 10' - $7.25</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="2" onclick="gettype(this.value)">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3. 14' - $9.25</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="3" onclick="gettype(this.value)">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>4. 16' - $12.90</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type=radio name=pizzatype value="4" onclick="gettype(this.value)">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; height: 2px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-width: 2px">
                <!-- START TEXT INPUTS -->
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">How many toppings do you want?</b>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">
                            <input id="toppingbox" type="text" style="width:50px;" />
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Do you want extra cheese?</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Yes
                            <input type=radio name=checkcheese value="1" onclick="getcheese(this.value)">
                            <br>No
                            <input type=radio name=checkcheese value="2" onclick="getcheese(this.value)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- END TEXT INPUTS -->
                <!-- CALCULATE BUTTON -->
                <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; height: 2px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-width: 2px">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
                </div>
                <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; height: 2px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-width: 2px">
                <!-- END CALCULATE BUTTON -->
                <!-- START TOTALS -->
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Subtotal:</td>
                        <td>$
                            <input id="subtotalbox" readonly="readonly" type="text" style="width:64px; background-color: #bdbdbd; font-weight:bold;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Tax Due:</td>
                        <td>$
                            <input id="taxbox" readonly="readonly" type="text" style="width:64px; background-color: #bdbdbd;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total Due:</td>
                        <td>$
                            <input id="totalbox" readonly="readonly" type="text" style="width:64px; background-color: #bdbdbd;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- END TOTALS -->
                <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:-8px; margin-top: 12px; height: 2px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-width: 2px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr noshade="noshade" style="text-align: center; width: 35%; height: 6px; color: gray; border-style: ridge; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px">
</body>

</html>
```

the cheesecost variable is supposed to change depending on the pizza size.  when the yes/no radio button is checked, it is supposed to either set the cheesecost to 0, or set it to the cheese price related to that specific pizza size.  ive been stuck on this for 3 days now, and ive tried about 12 different ways of doing this.  none of them seem to work.
for some reason the alert that displays the cheese cost is always zero, why is this?

Comment: I would use switch statements where you have multiple options and if/then when you have a yes/no answer. It'll make your code much more understandable.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: debugger? the only program i have is notepad++ portable, and notepad.  also, im only using a switch statement for that because i already tried an if/else statement with no luck, and i used a switch for the pizza type function

Comment: @BrandonDurst You can debug javascript with for example chrome developer tools. Nowadays nearly every browser has such functionality.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder im using a school computer and only have outdated IE

Comment: @BrandonDurst Ouch.. worst possible environment :S

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten to add the `break;` statement at the end of each `case`.

It should be:

```
case 1:
    {
        if(type==1)
        {
            cheesecost=1;
        }
        if(type==2)
        {
            cheesecost=1;
        }
        if(type==3)
        {
            cheesecost=1.25;
        }
        if(type==4)
        {
            cheesecost=1.4;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        cheesecost=0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: god dammit.  those always kill me.

Comment: @BrandonDurst you also need to `parseInt()` the value. It's a string if you don't.

Comment: Where is the variable 'type' coming from? It's not global and it's not being passed to the function as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MattBall parseInt() where specifically?

Comment: @theWizardsBaker type is in the gettype() function, do i need to set another variable to that value?

Comment: @BrandonDurst There is no change to your variable because type has no meaning to the getCheese function. You must either pass it to the function or make it a global (thought I would HIGHLY suggest you take a look at creating a 'pizza' object and not using global variables)

Answer (score 0):

why using function and case?

`switch(yesno){
      case 1:

```
      cheesecost = 1;
      break;
  case 2:
      cheesecost = 1;
      break;
  case 3:
      cheesecost = 1.25;
   ....
   default:
     system.out.print("wt* have u entered");`
```

You get an error because `type` is not defined.